# A desktop monitor that monitors desktop (the screen) for changes (upto a threshhold) and alert accordingly

Tags: autohotkey

Basically I want a "ding!" anytime "something changes" (like download finished, some dialog box completed, shell command returned etc,.).

Answer (score 2):

Make a screenshot of the screen, then take new screenshots periodicaly and compare it with the first screenshot using Imagesearch function

http://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/AutoHotkey:_Make_a_Screenshot_of_the_current_Window_with_Irfanview

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

You could also make a Timer that counts the number of shown windows using WinGet and List option.